# Optimize SVG and create SVG sprite - ruby middleman

Tags: ruby, optimization, svg, sprite, middleman

I'm running a middleman application which is based on ruby.
I have a folder full of SVG files I need to optimize them in order to create an SVG Sprite out of them.

I'm searching for gem that does that but I can't find anything, and I'm a newbie at ruby applications so I can't even know how to do that myself.

Is there anything that can help me?

Answer (score 2):

I *very* recently released a tool for this purporse, except using Nanoc. I haven't used Middleman, but since they're both static-site generators you should be able to fit it to your needs.

https://github.com/kylesimmonds/svg_spriter

It will take a folder of SVGs, optimize them using [svg_optimize](https://github.com/fnando/svg_optimizer), and compile them into a sprite.

A big caveat: it's at the lowest level in production right now, being only a minimally viable product. If you want to start learning more about Ruby and gem creation, I invite you to contribute to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the np for the sprite image creator

https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-sprite-generator

npm install -g svg-sprite-generator

Generate sprite by folder name:

svg-sprite-generate -d path/to/directory/of/svg/files -o path/to/sprite.svg

svg-sprite-generate -d svg/ -o sprite.svg